# asp.net core and ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, wikidata

I'm working on ASP.NET Core application and not sure what is right way to use ajax in it.

For example, I have model:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Wiki { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller, for show list of items:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Person.ToListAsync());
        }
```

And view:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>                
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>            
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I press on item I want to get item's details.

I have action `Details(int? id)` and view Details.cshtml.

And I created ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Birthday { get; set; }
        public string Death { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }            
    }
```

But this information I get from Wikidata using ajax.

I can run ajax by pressing link on the item and I get json from Wikidata.

But how I can populate ViewModel? For this I need to call action Details from ajax. But ajax usually used for get information on the current page (to avoid postback). So in this case it doesn't belong here.

Or I can call ajax when loading Detals view and populate page information. But in this case I don't need ViewModel at all.

What is right way to use ajax in my application?

Comment: I have a few questions

- How do you get the data from Wikidata? JQuery ajax?
- Do you want the details page to show up without a post-back like @Ajax.ActionLink in the Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: @Ody, actually I decided to use server side code instead ajax, see my other question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340003/making-http-request-by-ajax-or-c